# Error : error in connecting firebase to flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\flutter_windows_3.3.8-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 73
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Could not find method android() for arguments [flutter_cgpdejbg9282618bh70y27622$_run_closure1@2d7d97ba] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i tried to connect firebase with flutter app but faced this execption

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting [your project root]/android/ folder and then run this command

```
flutter create .
```

and then redo all the steps to install firebase on your project .